# Get PGP Private Key from RAM analysis RSAKeyFind

Tags: encryption, cryptography, forensics, rsa

For an experiment, I'm trying to open a 2048-bit RSA encrypted mail on a image. 
Using this fresh image, I made a memory dump and analysed the dump for RSA keys.

Now, several RSA keys have been found.

An example;

```
FOUND PRIVATE KEY AT 1048fb83
version = 
11 8e 48 04 06 11 
modulus = 
02 01 00 02 02 00 02 03 00 02 04 00 02 05 00 02 
06 00 02 07 00 02 08 00 02 09 00 02 0a 00 02 0b 
00 02 0c 00 02 0d 00 02 0e 00 02 0f 00 02 11 00 
02 12 00 02 13 00 02 14 00 02 15 00 02 16 00 02 
17 00 02 00 e0 02 01 e0 06 20 03 08 
publicExponent = 
0e 08 00 04 08 0e 03 08 
privateExponent = 
04 06 11 8e 54 07 20 01 
prime1 = 
12 8e 40 0d 00 04 11 8e 48 1d 0e 1d 0e 1d 
prime2 = 
0e 09 00 02 11 8e 48 1d 0e 1d 0e 06 00 01 11 8e 
48 08 07 00 02 02 1d 0e 1d 0e 05 00 01 
exponent1 = 
0e 0c 20 03 01 11 80 c8 11 80 c8 11 84 50 04 06 
11 8e 5c 05 06 0f 11 8e 68 05 06 0f 11 
exponent2 = 
06 00 00 1d 12 8f d0 06 00 01 12 8e 60 08 06 00 
00 0f 11 8e 68 06 00 00 0f 11 8e 6c 08 00 03 0f 
05 0e 08 10 18 04 06 12 8e 70 05 00 00 12 8e 70 
08 00 01 12 8e 70 12 8b 1c 07 00 01 0f 01 12 8b 
1c 08 00 02 0f 05 12 8b 1c 0e 05 08 00 12 8e 70 
04 0f 27 00 00 04 06 11 8e 78 05 00 00 12 8d c0 
06 20 01 01 11 8e 78 05 20 00 11 8e 
coefficient = 
20 02 08 0a 08
```

How does one continue from here?

I got a encrypted OpenPGP message; and I need to decode it with my own private key.

I've read about CRT formats, etc. I'm looking to convert these RSA parameter values to a value that OpenGPG can read. (One block of text).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the example you show, you don't continue far -- what is shown is *not* a valid RSA key pair, only something which superficially looked like one in the eyes of the tool you used.

Assuming you actually obtain a valid RSA key (you don't, apparently, but let's suppose that you find one), then your best bet would probably be to assemble the key with a small custom program invoking [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) (the library) or [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/). Or using the inherent capabilities of Java or .NET (both more or less know how to import and export private keys in PKCS#8 format).

I don't know of any good, easy to use ASN.1 DER encoding/decoding tools, except the ones I wrote (that was professionally, I cannot publish them as free software until I rewrite them from scratch, which I may do some day, but certainly not in the next few weeks).

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the answer. The tool found several possibilities. How could we identify a possible valid key pair quickly?

Comment: A valid key pair should have a long enough modulus (below 1024 bits = 128 bytes is improbable), a short public modulus (usually equal to 65537, almost always fitting on 4 bytes), and long enough prime integers. Both primes must be primes, therefore odd, and their product must be equal to the modulus, which should therefore be odd too. In-memory format of big integers in ASN.1 DER is big-endian, so the even/odd status can be seen on the last byte. Last but not least, a normal RSA keys "looks randomish"; it should not have that many zeros.

Comment: Also, [rsakeyfind](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/rsakeyfind.1.html) looks for ASN.1/DER-structured private keys, and OpenPGP does not use ASN.1, so it is unclear whether what you are trying to do may ever work at all.